# ¿Cómo centrar una imagen vertical y horizontalmente en un contenedor mas pequeño?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

hoy eh estada trabajando en un proyecto simple ya que eh estado aburrido. todo bien hasta que creé esta "galería de imágenes" y no pude encontrar la forma de que las imágenes se centraran, intente usando el siguiente código:

```
.contenedor{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.imagen{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

pero solo funciona cuando la imagen es mas pequeña que el contenedor.

aquí os dejo mi código:

```css
.A1_post-galery-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.A1_post-galery-item-container1{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.A1_post-galery-item-container2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.A1_post-galery-item{
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="A1_post-galery-container">
    <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container1">
        <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container2">
            <img src="https://cdn.computerhoy.com/sites/navi.axelspringer.es/public/styles/1200/public/media/image/2018/10/inventan-material-que-puede-convertir-olas-mar-electricidad.jpg?itok=IMODjeaT" alt="img" class="A1_post-galery-item">
        </div>
        <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container2">
            <img src="https://cdn.computerhoy.com/sites/navi.axelspringer.es/public/styles/1200/public/media/image/2018/10/inventan-material-que-puede-convertir-olas-mar-electricidad.jpg?itok=IMODjeaT" alt="img" class="A1_post-galery-item">
        </div>
        <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container2">
            <img src="https://cdn.computerhoy.com/sites/navi.axelspringer.es/public/styles/1200/public/media/image/2018/10/inventan-material-que-puede-convertir-olas-mar-electricidad.jpg?itok=IMODjeaT" alt="img" class="A1_post-galery-item">
        </div>
        <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container2">
            <img src="https://cdn.computerhoy.com/sites/navi.axelspringer.es/public/styles/1200/public/media/image/2018/10/inventan-material-que-puede-convertir-olas-mar-electricidad.jpg?itok=IMODjeaT" alt="img" class="A1_post-galery-item">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

me gustaría que las imágenes estuviesen centradas. de antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución con CSS es la siguiente:

```
.A1_post-galery-item{
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

Las propiedades top y left al 50% mueven la imagen al centro del div contenedor y transform translate X e Y al menos 50% la mueven media longitud del ancho y alto de la imagen hacia la izquierda y hacia arriba, de esta manera aparece centrada.

```css
.A1_post-galery-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.A1_post-galery-item-container1{
    flex: 1 2 auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 400px;
}
.A1_post-galery-item-container2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.A1_post-galery-item{
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="A1_post-galery-container">
    <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container1">
        <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container2">
            <img src="https://cdn.computerhoy.com/sites/navi.axelspringer.es/public/styles/1200/public/media/image/2018/10/inventan-material-que-puede-convertir-olas-mar-electricidad.jpg?itok=IMODjeaT" alt="img" class="A1_post-galery-item">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container1">
        <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container2">
            <img src="https://saludsinbulos.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/agua-de-mar-superemedio.jpg" alt="img" class="A1_post-galery-item">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container1">
        <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container2">
            <img src="https://www.conmishijos.com/assets/posts/14000/14825-adivinanzas-para-ninos-de-mar.jpg" alt="img" class="A1_post-galery-item">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container1">
        <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container2">
            <img src="https://services.meteored.com/img/article/-por-que-el-mar-es-azul--9441-2_1280.jpg" alt="img" class="A1_post-galery-item">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container1">
        <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container2">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEKxf-r2mHoRMpxXWRPr1IWXA7bvrct1-OmQ&usqp=CAU" alt="img" class="A1_post-galery-item">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container1">
        <div class="A1_post-galery-item-container2">
            <img src="https://www.josegonzalezbueno.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Crear-una-galeria-de-imagenes-responsive.jpg" alt="img" class="A1_post-galery-item">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: si sabia que podía hacer esto, el problema es que para que quedase centrada tenia que restar el tamaño medio de la imagen. y este era flexible lo que hice fue con ayuda de css grid establecer un tamaño fijo.
procedo a editar tu respuesta.